# can't able to fetch meta tag for particular url

Tags: php, web-scraping, keyword, meta-tags, simple-html-dom

I am using php script for fetch the keywords from meta tag for the particular website. but for some URL it is not working, when i manually check the keywords for that URL then i found that keywords are exist in the web page.

```
$url = "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/education/wp/2018/02/14/school-shooting-reported-at-florida-high-school/?tid=pm_pop";
    get_meta_tags($url);
```

It always give me warning:-

**Warning: get_meta_tags(https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/stormy-danielss-tale-gains-renewed-momentum-with-trump-lawyers-claim-which-raises-new-questions/2018/02/14/e7ce4a16-119d-11e8-9065-e55346f6de81_story.html?tid=pm_pop): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached**

Any Idea?

Comment: It seems that there's a redirect loop here:
curl -I https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/stormy-danielss-tale-gains-renewed-momentum-with-trump-lawyers-claim-which-raises-new-questions/2018/02/14/e7ce4a16-119d-11e8-9065-e55346f6de81_story.html?tid=pm_pop
...
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/stormy-danielss-tale-gains-renewed-momentum-with-trump-lawyers-claim-which-raises-new-questions/2018/02/14/e7ce4a16-119d-11e8-9065-e55346f6de81_story.html?tid=pm_pop

Comment: @DennisTrukhin is there any alternate to fetch the meta information?

Comment: @DennisTrukhin also when i tried to get keywords from online meta analyzer (http://analyzer.metatags.org/) then it gives me keywords for that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**let's go** :

- **first** : there's a **infinty** redirect loop ,**so** the server will give you the page only if you enable **`cookies`** .
  so we will use the **`curl` function**  to get the html page , by 2 step:

  1. get the cookies
  2. Resend cookies and get the page

---

- **second** : parsing html to get meta tags by using **`preg_match`** :
- **At last** the code will **be** :

  ```
  https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/education/wp/2018/02/14/school-shooting-reported-at-florida-high-school/?tid=pm_pop');
  //parsing begins here:
  preg_match_all('/<[\s]meta[\s](name|property)="?' . '([^>"])"?[\s]' . 'content="?([^>"])"?[\s][/]?[\s]*>/si', $html, $match);
  $count = count($match[2]);
  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
      echo($match[2][$i]." : ".$match[3][$i]."
  ");
  }
  ```

  function get_contents($link) {
   $result ="";
   try{
       $ch = curl_init(); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "-"); // <-- see here
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      // remember i didn't close the curl yet!
      // Now make another curl request with the same handle:
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      // if you are done, you can close it.
      $result = curl_exec($ch); 
      $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      $curlerr = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      $result = "Error1 :". $result."||".$e;
   }
  if(strlen($result) < 5){$result = $result."Error :".$httpcode.$curlerr;}
        return $result; 
  }
  ?>

**Note :** the html cannot be parsing by `domdocument`

**Output :**

```
object-hash : 1518960831
referrer : unsafe-url
keywords : Florida school shooting, Marjory Stoneman Douglas High School, Parkland school shooting, Florida shooting, Broward County
news_keywords : Florida school shooting, Marjory Stoneman Douglas High School, Parkland school shooting, Florida shooting, Broward County
twitter:card : summary_large_image
og:type : article
og:site_name : Washington Post
magnet : floridashooting
article:publisher : https://www.facebook.com/washingtonpost
fb:app_id : 41245586762
fb:admins : 4403963
fb:admins : 500835072
article:content_tier : metered
og:url : https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/education/wp/2018/02/14/school-shooting-reported-at-florida-high-school/
og:title : ‘A horrific, horrific day’: At least 17 killed in Florida school shooting
og:description : The suspect, a student who had been expelled, was armed with an AR-15, authorities said.
robots : index,follow
theme : normal
audio_url : 
twitter:creator : @lori_rozsa
article:author : https://www.facebook.com/moriah.balingit
author : https://www.facebook.com/moriah.balingit
twitter:creator : @ByMoriah
twitter:creator : @thewanreport
article:author : https://www.facebook.com/markberman
author : https://www.facebook.com/markberman
twitter:creator : @markberman
```

Comment: Thanks you @Mohamed SaȜed, Now it's working fine for me.